# Xamarin Forms - Achieve 2 columns with label / value pairs

Tags: layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tablelayout

Is it possible to achieve the following layout in Xamarin Forms:

[image]

**A couple of notes:**

1. Ideally I want a value to be able to wrap onto 2 lines - in which case the whole row would become taller (row meaning label 1, value 1, label 2, value 2).
2. Grid() has [known issues with word wrap](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17488/xamarin-forms-label-wont-word-wrap-inside-a-grid).

Comment: that looks like a grid to me

Comment: @Jason - I've updated the question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the known issues with Grid word wrapping?

Comment: @BillReiss - added link in question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you think grid has word wrapping issues. I've used grid in many of my apps exactly for this scenario. Here is the code.

```
<Grid
    ColumnSpacing="10"
    RowSpacing="10"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="Start">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label
      Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.Column="0"
      Text="label 1:"
      FontAttributes="Bold"
      HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
    <Label
      Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.Column="1"
      Text="value 1"/>

    <Label
      Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.Column="3"
      Text="label 2:"
      FontAttributes="Bold"
      HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
    <Label
      Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.Column="4"
      Text="value 2 is very very infinitely long and can potentially wrap to many many lines"/>

    <Label
      Grid.Row="1"
      Grid.Column="0"
      Text="label 3:"
      FontAttributes="Bold"
      HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
    <Label
      Grid.Row="1"
      Grid.Column="1"
      Text="value 3"/>

    <Label
      Grid.Row="1"
      Grid.Column="3"
      Text="label 4:"
      FontAttributes="Bold"
      HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
    <Label
      Grid.Row="1"
      Grid.Column="4"
      Text="value 4 goes here"/>

    <Label
      Grid.Row="2"
      Grid.Column="0"
      Text="label 5:"
      FontAttributes="Bold"
      HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
    <Label
      Grid.Row="2"
      Grid.Column="1"
      Text="value 5"/>

    <Label
      Grid.Row="2"
      Grid.Column="3"
      Text="label 6:"
      FontAttributes="Bold"
      HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
    <Label
      Grid.Row="2"
      Grid.Column="4"
      Text="value 6 here"/>

  </Grid>
```

And here are screenshots for iOS and Android

[image]

Comment: But in this example, does the first column (label 1/value 1, label 3/value 3, label 5/value 5) take up 50% width? (I've modified my screenshot to make that requirement clearer.) It appears that you're "cheating" by adding a hard width of 50 to a middle column to make it look like the first column spans half-way across.

Comment: In that case you need to have one parent grid with two columns with width set to "*", and in each of those columns another grid with the labels. but the approach is the same.

Comment: In that case, the label widths (of label 1/3/5, and label 2/4/6) won't line up. I might be willing for that solution, though - in my case, it might be acceptable to define a hard width for the labels (not values, just labels). That's essentially what I was doing before, but instead of using grids inside the main grid, I was using stacklayouts inside the main grid, with horizontal orientation so that you have the label on the left and the value on the right. But this is where I was running into word wrap issues (maybe a stacklayout inside a grid is the issue?)

Comment: Well that's already another requirement. But IMHO it's not a good idea, because when you localize your app you may have problems with fixed sizes. One other thing you could do is divide the screen into 2 equal sizes, and for "label i" labels set the HorizontalTextAlignment to End this way you'll have equally sized columns, and text will wrap accordingly. Try that.

Comment: Sorry not quite following, but I'm intrigued by any possible solution - when you say divide the screen into 2 equal sizes - do you mean a 1x2 Grid() to get 2 equal columns? But then how are the label/value pairs divided up? And wouldn't HorizontalTextAlignment = End right align the labels?